# TRIM function on Datefield in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the following query:

```
select * 
from employees  
order by (CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(JoingDate)) AS SMALLDATETIME)) desc
```

The query affects performance. Do we require to use `TRIM` on a `DateTime` column? How can we rewrite the above query to increase performance and to minimize execution time? Would we use `CONVERT` function instead of `CAST`?

Comment: No, `CONVERT` over `CAST` doesn't get you any speed up. What *might* help is: **(1)** don't select **all columns** (`SELECT *`) but only those that you **really need**, and **(2)** don't select **all rows** (by omitting a `WHERE` clause) ....

Comment: Get rid of the royal "we" first. It's your question. Use "I", "me" and "my". What does your `JoingDate` look like? `CAST` and `CONVERT` are pretty much the same so don't expect any performance gain from to the other.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is costly, an index will make it less costly, but I believe you'd need the `JoingDate` field to be in the proper data type in order to get any benefit from the index.

Comment: Why can't you simply run the different queries yourself to see if one is faster, or if you can remove the `TRIM`?

Comment: Why you are converting your date to a string and then back to a date?

Comment: Ths is not sargable if there is an index on JoingDate, it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, you should just do this:

```
select * 
from employees  
order by JoingDate desc
```

Not sure why you are converting your date to a string and then back to a date.  If you want smalldatetime over datetime, you could just cast/convert it but why?

```
select * 
from employees  
order by CAST(JoingDate AS SMALLDATETIME) desc
```

Comment: Possibly the date is stored in some sub optimal string format that does not sort chronologically.

Comment: @MartinSmith The OP specifically said in his post that it was a `DATETIME`. Perhaps it was not meant to be literal.